# How to change the application favicon in runtime?

Tags: gwt

I need to change the favicon depending on brand in runtime. When application starts I call webservice to establish the brand and then I need to configure the application. I don't know how to update favicon - is it possible?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon-brand1.ico">
```

To clarify the background of my need - my application is a GWT application, the requirement is to configure its appearance depending on domain name (**brand**) before it completes loading. So I have implemented web service which gives me all configuration data like site name, site description (placed in host HTML page in meta description) and associated favicon. 
I was able to update meta tags of my app but I couldn't find a solution how to update app's icon from GWT code instead of using JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any tag on your host page.

So something like this should work:

```
NodeList<Element> nodes = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("link");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  LinkElement link = LinkElement.as(nodes.getItem(i));
  if (link.getRel("shortcut icon") != null) {
    link.setHRef("favicon-brandNew.ico");
  }
}
```

Comment: I've optimized above code and now it looks like that:  

`NodeList<Element> links = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("link");
  for (int i = 0; i < links.getLength(); i++) {
   LinkElement link = ((LinkElement) links.getItem(i));
   if (link.getRel().equals("shortcut icon")) {
    link.setHref("favicon-brandNew.ico");
   }
  }`

Comment: You are right, I was looking for the wrong tag. I will update my answer with your code!

Comment: Great! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure of the context of your application but I'd imagine if you have this generated dynaically the right thing would just happen.

By this I mean specify the file name in a model property and use that in the view.

So, don't hard code it - look it up.

So you'd end up with somethiong along the lines of....

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@model.BrandFavIcon">
```